# Can a directed graph have two DFS traversals?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory, depth-first-search

[image: This is my input graph]

Here is my DFS traversal algorithm (Recursive approach):

```
def dfs(v,visited) :
    for i in Graph[v] :
        if i not in visited :
            visited.append(i)
            print(i)
            dfs(i,visited)

n = int(input())
Graph = {}
    for i in range(n) :
    name= input(print("Enter ",i+1," vertex name"))

    list_of_ver = list(map(int,input(print("Enter the vertices connected to ",name," vertex")).split()))

    Graph.update({int(name) : list_of_ver })
visited=[0]
print(Graph)
print("0")
dfs(0,visited)
```

The image above is my input graph.
My algorithm gives me different DFS traversal order : *0 1 2 3 4 5*
Is it correct ?

Comment: yes.   consider a binary tree with a root and 2 children.  You can visit the children in either order.

Comment: @ChristianSloper how many more Depth first traversal can it have ?

Comment: Depends on the graph of course

Comment: @ChristianSloper i got it. Thanks !